# How is the main image height always approximately 75% of the window size?

Tags: html, css

http://www.apple.com/sg/

there is a giant image that will autosize such that it is always approximately 75% of the window height.

How is this done?

I found a css media query, but I can only discover this one:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1068px), only screen and (max-height: 800px) {
   .page-home .billboard.evergreen {
       height: 50%;
       min-height: 630px;
    }
}
```

How do I find out about the other media queries for different resolutions?

Comment: `.page-home .billboard.evergreen { ...; height: 78%; ...; }`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way will be:

```css
.item
{
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

These are so called [viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). They are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) pretty good.

You may also try to utilize `vmax` for this use case. This will always hold the  larger value of `vw` or `vh`.